# Parsing a webpage using Beautiful Soup in python, doesnt work with specific page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

New to python, thought I'd try to make a web crawler as a first project. Found Beautiful Soup as the solution. All is well except that the ONE page I want to crawl yields no results :(

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

def crawl_list(max_pages):
    mech = Browser()

    place = 1
    while place <= max_pages:
        url = "http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/"
        page = mech.open(url)
        html = page.read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)

        place += 1

crawl_list(1)
```

This code works wonders. I get the whole list of links. BUT, as soon as I put http://diseasesdatabase.com/disease_index_a.asp in the value of 'url', no dice.

Perhaps it has to do with the .asp? Can someone please solve this mystery?

I'm getting this as an error message:

> mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 410: Gone

Thanks in advance.